# shut down computer while retaining LAN function

Tags: windows-7, router, lan, port-forwarding, shutdown

Well basically I have noticed that in hibernation mode the network card is still running (which means the router can detect that the computer is still in the network). Is there a way to do the same in shut down mode? (primarily I want to let the router know the location of the computer even during shut down)

To explain more of the situation, I am sending magic packets over internet, which requires port forwarding. But my router currently only allows forwarding to a specific IP address instead of a broadcast. This makes wake on WAN (WOW) unavailable in shut down mode since the computer will disappear from router network. Rather, in hibernation mode, since network card is still running, WOW can function properly. So, is there a way to allow the router knows the computer is here even it is in shut down mode?

Comment: Ok may I clarify this problem a bit more:
I HAVE NO PROBLEM WITH WOL (and DHCP) SETUP. Indeed WOL worked in LAN (in all situations), and WOW worked in hibernation. However WOW does not work in Shut Down.
The reason behind is, when the computer (lets say its LAN IP is 192.168.1.2) shuts down, it disappears from list of active devices as recognized by the router. This means when you send the magic packet from outside, and asked the router to forward it to 192.168.1.2, it has no idea where to send to.
So my problem is, how to make the router KNOWS the desktop is there even if it's shut down.

Answer (score 1):

From here:

http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-howto/29941-how-to-wake-on-lan-wake-on-wan?start=3

> Some routers don't allow broadcast IPs to be used as a target IP. This
>   is where having Static DHCP comes in handy. If you have configured
>   Static DHCP, and your router has the MAC of your target PC, you can
>   configure your router to forward the WOL packet directly to the IP
>   address of the target PC.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). I've fixed your answer to quote the referenced material.

Comment: Please note that setting a DHCP reservation (or whatever you want to call it) does not guarantee in any way that other programs/actions (namely port forwarding) will be able to use this information.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a Wake on LAN setting both on your BIOS and your NIC's firmware. Verify that they're both enabled. After that, the PC should retain its online status to the network. Here's an example of the WoL setting for the NIC:

[image]

[image]

You'll also probably want a static IP for your PC so you can easily send the magic packet directly to it. You can do it both ways: either on the PC itself (easiest way) or on the router (a.k.a. *DHCP Reservation*).

**On the PC:**

1. Search for `ncpa.cpl`.
2. Find your NIC from the list, right-click it, and choose `Properties`.
3. Choose **Internet Protocol Version 4** from the list.
4. Click the **Use the following IP address** radio button, and fill in the details as appropriate.
5. At the bottom, use any DNS server IPs that you like, then hit **OK**.

Answer (score 0):

> Just make sure the option “Shutdown Wake Up” on your NIC is set to
>   “Enabled”. This will allow the wake on lan of a Windows PC even after
>   a normal shutdown.

[source](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-wake-on-lan-in-windows-8/)